# Does riding bicycles reduce sperm count?

Tags: health, men-specific

I have heard this many times before. Is there scientific evidence for this fact? Or have any of you come across this in your lives?

Comment: Voting to close - medical advice.

Comment: @Batman, There's an old [meta question](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/99/on-or-off-topic-medical-advice) about whether medical advice questions are allowed.  Seems we allow some and not others. I think this question could be answered with references along with a disclaimer along the lines of "If you're feeling numbness or pain in the area go see a doctor."  The OP isn't asking about a medical condition they are having, but rather if it is know that cycling causes reduced sperm count.  Some people on this site probably have more info on that than many general practitioners.

Comment: I'd certainly hold off giving someone specific medical advice, but this question does appear to be somewhat more general in nature. I think it should be kept open.

Comment: See also [Does riding a bicycle reduce sperm count/male fertility?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4847/2703) on Skeptics.SE

Comment: It's not off-topic but it is a duplicate of a question already-asked.

Answer (score 2):

There are studies that link cycling to Erectile Dysfunction. A quick Google will point you toward further reading. I'm afraid I don't know what the link is (or indeed whether there is a link) between ED and sperm count.

The link between cycling an ED is because of pressure exerted on parts of your body while riding. You therefore won't find it surprising to learn that people will suggest one saddle design over another, with this in mind. How much substance there is in any of this......it's all subjective.

I think that, in general, though, the health benefits of cycling (helping to prevent e.g. heart disease) are considered to outweigh the risks. ED, for example, is in most cases temporary and reversible.